# Entity Framework adds "RenameTable" command when scaffolding migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have changed my model and is scaffolding a new migration using the `Add-Migration` package manager command.

However, for some reason, EF think that I have been renaming an object for one of my classes. The class names are similar in name and have similar properties and relationships.

The problem is that the `Update-Database` command fails because of the rename. The very first command is `RenameTable()` and later on the migration tries to delete an index on the table that has been renamed (and doesn't exist anymore).

I would like to force EF to scaffold a migration where the old table is dropped and a new one is created instead. How do I achieve this? My impression was that EF can't be "smart" when figuring out renames and should always drop tables that are no longer mapped to an entity.

Comment: As a comment, I would like to note that I tried to rename the entity name (C# class name) and the name of the table it is mapped to in order to see if it was the naming that caused EF to try to be smart. But it is still causing the scaffold to do a RenameTable() instead of a DropTable() + CreateTable(). The only thing that makes the two similar are the relationships and properties on the class. (They share all the same relationships except for one.)